Can't use SDL2 with rust (MacOS)
I was trying to use SDL2 with rust and failed to do so. I was following along with everything on their github page but couldn't get it working. Here's what I've done so far.
I downloaded the framework from libsdl.org and put it under /Library/Frameworks/
Here's my build.rs
fn main() {
println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=framework=/Library/Frameworks")
}

And here is cargo.toml
[package]
name = "gamee"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"
build = "build.rs"

[dependencies.sdl2]
version = "*"
features = ["use_mac_framework"]

cargo build runs successfully but when I run cargo run, I get this error
Running `target/debug/gamee`
dyld[85941]: Library not loaded: @rpath/SDL2.framework/Versions/A/SDL2
Referenced from: <DBF38183-3DAF-38E0-BC8F-CC18E1E07066>     /Users/ayush/SDL2/gamee/target/debug/gamee
Reason: no LC_RPATH's found
zsh: abort      cargo run

I have no idea how to solve this issue.

Adding this to my build.rs worked for me
println!("cargo:rustc-link-arg=-Wl,-rpath,/Library/Frameworks");

